# Playing with network interfaces in C/C++

Tags: networking, c, c++

I've been looking for a way to manipulate network configurations. Required functions are;

1. Set/get ip/netmask of an interface.
2. Set/get route table information.
3. Add/remove networks from/to route table.
4. Add/remove virtual interfaces (such as ppp0).
5. Up/down network interfaces
6. Get general information about the interface (such as received/transmitted byte count, flags, mac address etc.)

There is a huge amount of "piece-of-codes" on the web to implement one of the functions described above but couldn't find a proper source that contains good documentation regarding those topics.

Does anyone know what is the topic that I should search? Or can anyone offer a resource/guide that I can read or follow?

Just stuck a little bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much dependent on the operating system. If you are targeting Linux, you could have a look at how the `ip` command from the Iproute2 package does this.